# How to avoid unfortunate side-effects when using synchronized

Tags: android, synchronized

This [@Synchronized](http://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized.html) commentary warns that:

> Locking on this or your own class object can have unfortunate
>   side-effects, as other code **not under your control** can lock on
>   these objects as well, which can cause race conditions and other nasty
>   threading-related bugs.

Avoiding race conditions is exactly the reason why I need to use the [synchronized](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_nonaccess_modifiers.htm) modifier, but when I see a warning like this, I realize that I may be causing more harm than good by not knowing *everything* about the system for which I am programming...

In my particular situation, I need to make sure that a specific method of a `WebView`-subclass is not interrupted by a `PictureListener.onNewPicture()`.

That method was written by me, but it is only invoked by a Runnable.run() via a timer handler.

What should I check before deciding that it is safe to use the `synchronized` modifier to make sure that that timer-invoked method is not interrupted by `PictureListener.onNewPicture()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a private object to serve as the object's lock, like this:

In the class definition:

```
private Object syncRoot=new Object();
```

or

```
private static Object syncRoot=new Object();
```

In your code:

```
synchronized(syncRoot){
  // put your code here
}
```

The reason why race conditions can occur is that other code has access to the objects locked on.  Locking only private objects solves this.

Comment: I just realized that this is actually hinted at in the quote I posted, but what you've written is much clearer and explanatory. +1

Answer (score 1):

Have a property in a class that you syncronhize on, rather than synchronizing on `this` or WebView-subclass `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of those side effects would mostly affect server systems. I don't think that on Android you will have much of the problem as there is not much `other code` that could touch your method.

Comment: I would like to use this your answer to simplify my code, but I am not knowledgeable enough about Android inner-workings to rely on this. If there is a specific source that documents, for example, that timer calls are always interleaved between `onNewPicture()` events, that would suffice, but I don't know that.

Comment: My point is that there will be not so many collisions to affect performance. There would be some, otherwise you would not need `synchronized`.